# How to read HDF data from HDFS for Hadoop

Tags: matlab, hadoop, hive, distributed-computing, hdf

I am working in Image processing on Hadoop. I am using HDF satellite data for processing, I can access and use jpg and other image types of data in hadoop streaming. But while using HDF data it comes with error. Hadoop couldnt read HDF data from HDFS. It takes more than twenty minutes to show the error also. My HDF data size is more than 150MB single file.

How to solve this problem. How to make hadoop can read this HDF data from HDFS.

Some of my code

```
hadoop@master:/usr/local/master/hdf/examples$ ./runD1.sh


Buildfile: /usr/local/master/hdf/build.xml

downloader:

setup:

test_settings:

compile:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
Output HIB: /var/www/html/uploads/
14/09/26 15:28:46 WARN mapred.JobClient: Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the     arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
Found host successfully: 0
Repeated host: 1
Repeated host: 2
Repeated host: 3
Tried to get 2 nodes, got 1
14/09/26 15:28:46 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
First n-1 nodes responsible for 1592259 images
Last node responsible for 1592259 images
14/09/26 15:29:04 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201409191212_0006
14/09/26 15:29:05 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/09/26 15:39:15 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :    attempt_201409191212_0006_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Task attempt_201409191212_0006_m_000000_0 failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing!
14/09/26 15:49:17 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201409191212_0006_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Task attempt_201409191212_0006_m_000000_1 failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing!
14/09/26 15:59:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201409191212_0006_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
 Task attempt_201409191212_0006_m_000000_2 failed to report status for 600 seconds. Killing!
```

Error log is:

```
2014-09-26 15:38:45,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: In JvmRunner constructed JVM ID: jvm_201409191212_0006_m_-1211757488
2014-09-26 15:38:45,133 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM Runner    jvm_201409191212_0006_m_-1211757488 spawned.
2014-09-26 15:38:45,136 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskController: Writing commands to /usr/local/master/temp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201409191212_0006/attempt_201409191212_0006_m_000000_0.cleanup/taskjvm.sh
2014-09-26 15:38:45,631 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: JVM with ID: jvm_201409191212_0006_m_-1211757488 given task: attempt_201409191212_0006_m_000000_0
2014-09-26 15:38:46,145 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201409191212_0006_m_000000_0 0.0% 
2014-09-26 15:38:46,198 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: attempt_201409191212_0006_m_000000_0 0.0% cleanup
2014-09-26 15:38:46,200 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: Task attempt_201409191212_0006_m_000000_0 is done.
2014-09-26 15:38:46,200 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: reported output size for attempt_201409191212_0006_m_000000_0  was -1
2014-09-26 15:38:46,200 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker: addFreeSlot : current free slots : 2
2014-09-26 15:38:46,340 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JvmManager: JVM : jvm_201409191212_0006_m_-1211757488 exited with exit code 0. Number of tasks it ran: 1
```

Please can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Which `InputFormat` you are using ?

Comment: My Input Data format is HDF (extension).

Comment: I was pointing to the Mapreduce `InputFormat` not HDF. Can you please post the contents of runD1.sh ?

Comment: #!/bin/bash

./runDownloader2.sh /usr/O2_01AUG2013_010_012_GAN_L1B_ST_S.hdf /var/www/html/uploads/mynew2 2

Comment: Without runDownloader2.sh it'll still difficult to guess. Please update your question.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
hadoop jar downloader.jar $1 $2 $3

that downloader.jar file is for split the job to slave nodes. $1 is for input $2 is for output path $is for number of nodes which it can use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62097/discussion-between-blacksmith-and-prabu).